# Errors in installing OpenMPI on El Capitan

Tags: macos, administrator, sudo, open-source

I'm following [this guide](https://intothewave.wordpress.com/2011/12/27/install-open-mpi-on-mac-os-x/) to install OpenMPI on my Mac. I *think* everything is going well, but now I'm at the step where I have to `make all`. When I try, I get the error `Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.`, so I can't go further.

**EDIT**: looking at the downvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485555/agreeing-to-the-xcode-ios-license-requires-admin-privileges-please-re-run-as-ro) I tried to run Xcode and say ok to license agreement.
Now, when I enter `make all` I get the error in the following figure

[image: screenshot]

Indeed, I see there's no file named `makefile` (only `Makefile.*` files are present).

I don't know why but a second `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` solved the problem of `make all`, which is currently in execution. Maybe the license agreement should have been done before this step.

Comment: There is no need to delete the question. You may answer the question yourself!

Comment: Yes the license agreement was required first. confgure calls the C compiler and the first run would have reported errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution to my problem. The the license agreement was required to be completed *before* `./configure --prefix=/usr/local` (as I suspected and @klanomath confirmed). If not so, the command `make all` can't be run.